# Javascript window.postmessage() help - don't understand usage

Tags: javascript, web

I'm planning to make use of websockets to make a domain-specific chat tool. I have this code so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chatroom Dev Stage</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function submit(form) {
    var win=document.getElementbyId(iframe).contentWindow
    win.postmessage(form.msg.value, 
<body>
<h3>Conversation:</h3>
<iframe height="150px" width="300px" id="iframe"></iframe> 
<br>
<form name="sendmsg">
   <input type="text" id="msg"></input>
   <button onclick="submit()">Send</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It creates an iframe that will show the messages in the conversation. The `<input> messagebox` will be where the user types their message. This will be entirely client-based, and will not be attached or have access to a server.

QUESTION:
I don't understand how to send the message over a network to another computer (syntax of the command, IP adresses, etc) and also how to use the command `window.postmessage()`.

P.S - As a new user, could someone please tell me how, if need be, I can improve my question asking ethics, in case it isn't good?

Comment: im planning running this on the local wifi, not on the web. This will be running at my workplace, and I will only be connected to the wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take what you want to send and put it in a json object (http://www.json.org/js.html)

And use an AJAX call to send it to the other computer within your wifi network: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php